Statusbar not showing up in expo project that I just started
I just started an expo project and in older versions I had no such problem, I just ran 2 commands, npx create-expo-app@latest and npm run reset-project.
I only have one file, which is index.js and I was searching the web for solutions for the last 4-5 hours, but I can't find a solution that works.
Screenshot:

I looked into app.json, tried the expo statusbar, the react native statusbar, I updated expo go on my phone, tried to put into view, safeareaview, tried to style the statusbar, I can't even comprehend how is it even possible for the statusbar to not show up if I haven't done anything in this project.
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <StatusBar />
      <Text>
        Hello world!
      </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


To automatically follow light and dark modes add the following configuration. The default is light.
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
  }
}

The status bar follows this automatically. When added manually to layout there is the style property which can be used to control this.
<StatusBar style="auto" />

See Configuring the status bar and Color themes for details.

Thank you for your answer!
So I tried it and if I set it to auto it still doesn't work, but if I set it to dark it does.
Could there be a solution for this or is it going to be a problem going forward, when I try it on different devices or is it okay to leave it on dark?

Did you set "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"?

I did, since then i closed vs code turned my pc off and turned itt back on again now, and now it isn't even working with dark

Now i was just trying some props and now it works with barStyle="default"
